# Can I get EU residence permit while keeping my current non-EU job and taxation?

Tags: resident-permit, eu, residency

I'm not an EU citizen but my job is remote so I can stay wherever I want and with my native country's taxation policy the net salary seems good enough to stay in many EU countries. So I wonder if a residence permit is possible without me getting an EU job and/or paying some taxes in EU. Also, maybe the answer varies country-based. Is it different from one country to another or there's some common set of requirements/procedures?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most countries tax based on residence.  If you work remotely from the EU, you'll owe tax to the EU country to which you move, but you probably won't owe tax in the country where you now live.  The details are certainly different in each EU country.

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder if a residence permit is possible without me getting an EU job […]

It's possible but you will need another basis for it. For example residing with a spouse who themselves qualify for residence based on their EU citizenship or some national residence permit. It will be difficult to secure one on the basis of your non-EU job although some digital nomad programmes are beginning to appear that could be relevant (I heard about Malta, Estonia, Portugal, possibly Spain soon).

Some EU countries have long-term visitor status without no specific purpose requirement but then you won't have the right to work (and that typically means not performing work while being present on the territory, not merely not getting a local job) and prove you have sufficient financial resources.

> and/or paying some taxes in EU

Physical presence can trigger tax and other related rules. That is whether you do require a visa or residence permit or not (e.g. if you were an EU citizen), you have to check the rules of the countries where you spend some time. Unless you are covered by some explicit exemption, income tax, healthcare contributions, etc. might all be required, even for a remote job.

This is not directly related to the visa. In fact, your being present and working in the country is what triggers both the requirement to hold a work and residence permit and to pay taxes, not the other way around.

> Also, maybe the answer varies country-based. Is it different from one country to another or there's some common set of requirements/procedures?

It's strictly dependent on the country, no common requirements/procedures, save of the fact that if you do secure a residence permit in a Schengen country, it will exempt you from any visa requirement for short visits to all other EU countries (Schengen and non-Schengen), except Ireland.

Answer (score 1):

Most European countries - actually the majority of countries - will want residents to pay taxes for all their income they made while within the country. Whether you have a permit usually doesn’t matter, but the actual fact that you are a resident (including illegal immigrants, visa overstayers also count).

If you work remotely, what counts for taxes is where your actually body is. That country will want your income tax. There are some poorer countries that made an exception and assume that some EU citizen moving there will spend plenty of money and help the country financially that way. In the EU - no chance.